# Azure : Create Azure AD Groups along with Role using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I’m trying to create list of Azure AD Groups along with Role using Terraform

I have followed approach in such a way it would first create the required AD groups and then later it will assign the Role

```
# Required Provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  ....
  ....
}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

# Variables
variable "ad_groups" {
  description = "Azure AD groups to be added"
  type = list(object({
    display_name = string,
      description  = string,
    scope        = string,
    role         = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      display_name = "Group1"
      description  = "some description",
      scope        = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxxx",
      role         = "Owner"
    },
    {
      display_name = "Group2"
      description  = "some description",
      scope        = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxxx",
      role         = "Contributor"      
    }
  ]
}

# Create AD Groups and add the Current User
resource "azuread_group" "this"{
  count = length(var.ad_groups)
  display_name =  var.ad_groups[count.index].display_name
  description = var.ad_groups[count.index].description
  security_enabled = true
  # prevent_duplicate_names = true  
  owners  = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

# Assign Permission to the AD Group
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sp-tenant-global-admin-user-access-role-assignment" {
  count = length(var.ad_groups)
  scope                = var.ad_groups[count.index].scope
  role_definition_name = var.ad_groups[count.index].role
  principal_id         = azuread_group.this[count.index].object_id

  depends_on = [
    azuread_group.this
  ]  
}
```

does it look good and would it work? I don't have access to run the above code to validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

```
variable "ad_groups" {
  description = "Azure AD groups to be added"
  type = list(object({
    display_name = string,
      description  = string,
    scope        = string,
    role         = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      display_name = "Group2"
      description  = "some description",
      scope        = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxxx",
      role         = "Reader"      
    }
  ]
}

# Create AD Groups and add the Current User
resource "azuread_group" "this"{
  count = length(var.ad_groups)
  display_name =  var.ad_groups[count.index].display_name
  description = var.ad_groups[count.index].description
  security_enabled = true
  owners  = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

# Assign Permission to the AD Group
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sp-tenant-global-admin-user-access-role-assignment" {
  count = length(var.ad_groups)
  scope                = var.ad_groups[count.index].scope
  role_definition_name = var.ad_groups[count.index].role
  principal_id         = azuread_group.this[count.index].object_id

  depends_on = [
    azuread_group.this
  ]  
}
```

***I have received error like:***

[image]

- As I donot have role over the scope of the subscription, as the
  `/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxx`   need
  privilege to assign role over the subscription scope.
- But as you are using azurerm provider to create a role to group via
  terraform ,  I tried the following code with a resource group scope
  as I checked  it is enough for my groups

Code:

***Variables.tf***

```
variable "ad_groups" {
  description = "Azure AD groups to be added"
  type = list(object({
    display_name = string,
      description  = string,
    scope        = string,
    role         = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      display_name = "Group2"
      description  = "some description",
      scope        = "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/myrg" #resource group scope
      role         = "Reader"      
    }
  ]
}
```

***Main.tf:***

```
resource "azuread_user" "example" {
  display_name        = "kavyaJDoe"
  password            = "notSecure123"
  user_principal_name = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
}


resource "azuread_group" "example" {
  display_name     = "kavyaMyGroup"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  security_enabled = true

  members = [
    azuread_user.example.object_id,
    # more users 
   ]
}


resource "azuread_group" "this"{
  count = length(var.ad_groups)
  display_name =  var.ad_groups[count.index].display_name
  description = var.ad_groups[count.index].description
  security_enabled = true
  # prevent_duplicate_names = true  
  owners  = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sp-tenant-global-admin-user-access-role-assignment" {
  count = length(var.ad_groups)
  scope                ="/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/myrg"     
  role_definition_name = var.ad_groups[count.index].role
  principal_id         = azuread_group.this[count.index].object_id

  depends_on = [
    azuread_group.this
  ]  
}
```

> **Optional** :if role is required to be assigned in order to provide roles to others:
>
> ```
> resource "azurerm_role_definition" "role_assignment_write_delete" {
>      name  = "RBAC Owner"
>      scope = data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id
>      description = "Management of role assignments"
>     
>      permissions {
>          actions = [
>              "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write",
>              "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/delete",
>          ]
>          not_actions = []
>      }
>     
>      assignable_scopes = [
>          data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id //or management group
>      ]
>  }
> ```

***I could create the role assignment successfully:***

[image]

***Can see the role created for  the group2 that got initiated through variables:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[Understand scope for Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/scope-overview)